# How To change theme colors on Nuxt/Vuetify starter template

Tags: vue.js, styles, vuetify.js

### Change colors

I'm trying to use Vue with Nuxt and Vuetify for the styles, on Vuetify exists many templates, one of them brings all.

I tried to add colors on /assets/style/app.styl without effect.

Also on /plugins/vueitfy.js add something like:

```
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
    theme: {
     header: '#48393C',
     footer: '#2f3542'
    }
})
```

Without effects, i think that the last way is the best way for do it.

Comment: Did you try with primary and not header.. I think that those are predefined and can be overridden, header and footer you have to declare in themeOptions

Answer (score 3):

In `Vuetify 2`, for example, if you want ro override `background colour` (`nuxt js`):

1. Create `.\assets\style\variables.scss`

```css
    @import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';

    $material-light: map-merge($material-light, (
            background: map-get($blue, 'lighten-5'),
            calendar: (background-color: red),
    )
    );
```

2. In `nuxt.config.js` add:

```js
    import colors from 'vuetify/lib/util/colors'


    buildModules: ['@nuxtjs/vuetify'],
    vuetify: {
        treeShake: true,
        customVariables: ['~/assets/style/variables.scss']
        theme: {
            options: {customProperties: true},
            themes: {
                light: {
                    primary: colors.blue.lighten5,
                    secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
                    accent: colors.grey.darken3,
                    info: colors.teal.lighten1,
                    warning: colors.amber.base,
                    error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
                    success: colors.green.accent3
                }
    }
```

More info:

1. https://vuetifyjs.com/ru/customization/sass-variables
2. https://vuetifyjs.com/ru/customization/theme

Answer (score 1):

There are two options to change the color theme
1. from the /plugins/vueitfy.js

```
    Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
    primary: '#2c3e50',
    secondary: '#1abc9c',
    accent: '#2980b9',
    error: '#e74c3c',
    action: '#23DB2A'
  }})
```

2. From /assets/style/appl.styl, before the require of vuetify

`$theme := {
   primary: '#2c3e50',
   secondary: '#1abc9c',
   accent: '#2980b9',
   error: '#e74c3c',
   action: '#23DB2A'
        }`

And header and footer won't work as a color theme property

Comment: `> And header and footer won't work as a color theme property` Incorrect, you can define your own colors, and they should work. Obviously it wont apply automatically to header(i.e. toolbar) and footer respectively, but you can set `color="header"` on any element which accepts color prop, and it will apply the color that you have set (also class="header" will apply the custom color).

Comment: Please clarify option 2. I tried that and it does not work. Where should `$theme` be used? My code is as follows:
`// Import Vuetify styling
$theme := {
   primary: '#2c3e50',
   secondary: '#1abc9c',
   accent: '#2980b9',
   error: '#e74c3c',
   action: '#23DB2A'}
 
@import '~vuetify/src/stylus/main'`