# Nuxt + Vuetify. How to apply theme colors

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I am using a Nuxt.js + Vuetify.js project

Looking at the file `assets/style/app.styl` we have

```
// Import and define Vuetify color theme
// https://vuetifyjs.com/en/style/colors
@require '~vuetify/src/stylus/settings/_colors'
$theme := {
  primary:     $blue.darken-2
  accent:      $blue.accent-2
  secondary:   $grey.lighten-1
  info:        $blue.lighten-1
  warning:     $amber.darken-2
  error:       $red.accent-4
  success:     $green.lighten-2
}

// Import Vuetify styling
@require '~vuetify/src/stylus/main'

.page
  @extend .fade-transition
```

The problem is, changing these theme colors does not result in any changes.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To change theme colors on Nuxt/Vuetify starter template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49116469/how-to-change-theme-colors-on-nuxt-vuetify-starter-template)

Comment: Already checked this, did not work for me

Comment: Then I suggest add more details. Question basically looks same to me at this state. What do you mean by "this", and what did "not work"?

Comment: It had no effect when I changed the theme, according to the suggestions in the link you provided.

Comment: And there isnt that much info to give that I know of, I'm using a quickstart template from nuxt, this quickstart template, amongst other stuff, created a bunch of files. Changing the theme object as described above made no difference. I think that what I need is to include something in the nuxt.config.js file, but I dont know

Comment: Try my answer (posted as answer, and not a comment because of formatting). Let me know if it works?

Comment: Have you fixed this issue ?

Comment: Yes and no. There was never an issue. I thought that by defining a theme, vuetify would apply the theme colors automatically according to components. I was wrong. Sorry

Comment: Am still facing this problem, did you get any luck fixing this?

Comment: Yeah I did, the problem was myself, I thought that the theme colors would somehow be applied "intelligently" by vuetify, but as it turns out, you will need to choose the color for everything yourself

Answer (score 22):

Docs not telling how to change color properly...

first of all you need to set your current theme and then config it.
I've waste 4 hours to figure this out. You need to change you config accordingly:

```
vuetify: {
        theme: {
            light: true,  //you don't actually need this line as it's for default
            themes: {
                light: {
                    primary: '#b71c1c',
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

---

While working on this problem I figured out that you also can freely add your colors like this:

```
vuetify: {
        theme: {
            themes: {
                light: {
                    'custom-color-one': '#b71c1c',
                    'custom-color-two': '#3B8070',
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

and then in your HTML:

```
<div class='custom-color-one'>
  I'am div with custom background color!
</div>

<div class='custom-color-one--text'>
  I'am div with custom text color!
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed to use themes in the theme object.

Comment: @Виктор Кондик  do you know how can we use the custom-color-one in scoped css?

Comment: @uneeb meer I don't think it's possible. Theme styles are global by design, so I guess you should use special names if you want to make them scoped

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but try this maybe, depends how vuetify is included, but I presume if you used vuetify nuxt template then you need to include it in your `nuxt.config.js` file.
If you included vuetify like so:

```
modules: [
 '@nuxtjs/vuetify'
```

Then add theme like so:

```
module.exports = {
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify'
    // ...
  ]
  // Add the following:  
  vuetify: {
    theme: {
      secondary: '#ff0000'
      // ...
    }
  },
```

Comment: No luck...I had Vue.use('Vuetify') under `plugins`, removed that and applied your changes, but nothing changed. The only thing I've been able to do, is to change `<v-app>` to `<v-app dark>` in `layouts/default.vue`, which produced a dark theme.

Comment: thanks for the advice though ... I think I've misconfigured something terribly

Comment: @isebarn Basically in your `vuetify.js` you should do like so `Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
    secondary: '#FF0000',
  }
})`. It should work. But maybe just explain your installation process and which changes you made, and code that proves that changes are not applied. Note if you changed config then probably you need to recompile. See if there is `mode: 'universal'` in your `nuxt.config.js` as well I guess.

Comment: I tried adding the 'universal' thing to the config file, no change. I guess I'm going to reset the project and try to figure out what has gone wrong. I'll update this question and tag you when I figure it out

Comment: @isebarn anything new? have the same issue, NuxtJS not updating my primary color. .

Answer (score 1):

***NOTE**: This solution isn't the best approach, and will not work in a production environment. It works for workflows where a static site is deployed (i.e. when you run `yarn build` and deploy that), since changes in node_modules aren't persistent across installs.*

Two files govern this - **`nuxt.config.js`** and **`node_modules/vuetify/es5/colors.js`**.

You need to open **nuxt.config.js**, and head over to the `vuetify` property. The `themes` property under the `vuetify: {...}` section lets you map the class names to configured color variables.

Further, to change the values of the colour variables, modify the file **node_modules/vuetify/es5/colors.js**. Here, you define any colors you need to whatever hex color code you want.

Comment: This is a bad advice, you don't want to edit the node_modules because the changes will only apply in your local machine. If you deploy this in production, you won't have the changes anymore

Comment: Totally agree. I have updated the answer. Thanks for pointing this out. I'd be happy to make further changes if you have more to add.