# How to use Font-Awesome SVG with Vuetify and Nuxt.js

Tags: font-awesome, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to use the Font-Awesome SVG icons with Vuetify. But I don't manage to display icons.

I installed the necessary packages with:

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons -D
```

And the Vuetify plugin file looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
library.add(fas)

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  iconfont: 'faSvg',
  theme: {
    primary: colors.blue.darken2,
    accent: colors.grey.darken3,
    secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
    info: colors.teal.lighten1,
    warning: colors.amber.base,
    error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
    success: colors.green.accent3
  }
})
```

Trying to show a icon:

```
<v-icon color="white" round>fa-times</v-icon>
```

Comment: The syntax is I think  `icons: {
    iconfont: 'faSvg',
  }`

Comment: No. Icons is for something different.

Comment: Ah, my bad. The syntax I mentioned is for vuetify v2.

Comment: Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Quickly glanced and I guess you just did as the vuetify docs says so that should be fine. But are you sure that vuetify config is applied from your `vuetify.js` file? e.g. if you change primary color in theme here, does it have any effect? You are using nuxt so it might depend on your nuxt config, maybe you need to place vuetify config in nuxt config file or something... Depends how your project was set up.  See for example this non-related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56076778/1981247 wherein I had to put theme config elsewhere (depends on how nuxt was installed).Other than that no idea

Comment: I used the Nuxt Vuetify template. So the whole thing should work.

Answer (score 10):

It's really simple. `Nuxt js` + `Vuetify 2`:

1. `npm i -D @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`

U can check your `package.json` file:

```js
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.11.2"
}
```

2. In `nuxt.config.js` file:

```js
vuetify: {
    defaultAssets: {icons: 'fa'}
}
```

That's all! U can use:

```html
<v-icon>fa-times</v-icon>
```

Comment: Looks like you are using the @nuxtjs/vuetify module. However you are using the font icons not the svg icons with your defaultAssets setting. :)

Comment: Just wanted to add, according to the [docs](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module#defaultassets), the module will automatically pull the icons from the cdn `defaultAssets.icons automatically adds the icons stylesheet from a CDN to load all the icons (not optimized for production).`

Comment: Why is loading the CSS from CDN not viable for production? Sounds like using a CDN is exactly what you'd want in production.

Comment: Also, this answer does not address the question correctly. It's not using the SVG variant of the icons. It's using the icon-font.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `icons: { iconfont: 'faSvg' }` syntax.

If anyone is using the `@nuxtjs/vuetify` module, you can configure the iconset in vuetify to use `faSvg` and then use the [fontawesome-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/fontawesome-module) for SVG icons. At this time of writing, vuetify is using the free solid icons in most of its components, so including all solid icons should be enough. You can configure this in the `fontawesome-module` so:

```
  ...otherNuxtConfigStuff,
  buildModules: [
    ...otherBuildModules,
    // https://github.com/nuxt-community/fontawesome-module
    ['@nuxtjs/fontawesome', {
      icons: {
        solid: true,
        // here you can include other icons you need
        brands: [
          'faYoutube',
          'faVimeo',
          'faVimeoV'
        ]
      }
    }],
    // https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module
    ['@nuxtjs/vuetify', {
      ...otherVuetifyConfigStuff,
      icons: {
        iconfont: 'faSvg'
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Make sure you don't change the `component` option in the fontawesome configuration because vuetify uses the default component name `font-awesome-icon`.