# How to use vuetify theme colors in custom scss file in assets

Tags: css, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I  have defined custom colors in Nuxt+Vuetify:

```
vuetify: {
    theme: {
         options: {customProperties: true},
         themes: {
              light: {
                   primary: {
                        lighten1: '#AFB5D1' //inactive icons
                   }
              }
         }
    }
}
```

Also added file elements.scss in nuxt config css: `~assets/style/elements.scss`
where I want to use color primary-lighten.

```
.separator {
     color: var(--v-primary-lighten1);
}
```

I expect to see color `#AFB5D1` on my page for element marked with class separator. In chrome inspector class looks correct but color has not parsed and color is not applied.
What I' am doing wrong?

Comment: Which version on Vuetify / Nuxt + Vuetify are you working?

Comment: latest: "nuxt": "^2.12.2", "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.0"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56734584/4523764
hope this will help!! else update here once