# How do I change the vuetify theme background color

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

The default vuetify themes have a very limited amount of properties to tweak.

```
dark: {
    primary: '#3739FF',
    accent: '#101721',
    secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
    info: colors.teal.lighten1,
    warning: colors.amber.base,
    error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
    success: colors.green.accent3
}
```

I want to have control over all the background colors.

I tried the answer from Dmitry Kaltovich

[How To change theme colors on Nuxt/Vuetify starter template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49116469/how-to-change-theme-colors-on-nuxt-vuetify-starter-template?rq=1)

By having a custom scss file like this

```
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';

$material-dark: map-merge(
  $material-dark,
  (
    background: map-get($blue, 'lighten-5'),
  )
);
```

and my nuxt config like this

```
vuetify: {
    treeShake: true,
    customVariables: ['~/assets/scss/vuetify.scss'],
    theme: {
        dark: true,
        themes: {
            options: {customProperties: true},
            dark: {
                primary: '#3739FF',
                accent: '#101721',
                secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
                info: colors.teal.lighten1,
                warning: colors.amber.base,
                error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
                success: colors.green.accent3
            }
        }
    }
},
```

But it does not work.

I'm using

```
"nuxt": "^2.14.6",
"@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.2",
"sass": "^1.29.0",
"sass-loader": "^7.3.1"
"fibers": "^5.0.0",
"node-sass": "^5.0.0",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well everything is almost right except one thing.

You need to have `sass-loader` version **8.x** to make it work with `customVariables:` part. Install it with `npm install -D sass-loader@8` This because of `sass-loader` takes additional data different way in different versions. [more information about sass-loader](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#webpack-install)

After that, you should be able to override framework variables thru editing `vuetify.scss` file.

```
/* Example of `~assets/scss/vuetify.scss` */

@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';

// theme to override, same applies for $material-light
$material-dark: map-merge(
  $material-dark,
  (
    'background': rgb(130, 130, 130),
    'text': (
      'primary': map-get($grey, 'lighten-2'),
    ),
    'calendar': (
      background-color: red,
    ),
  )
);
```

What happens in here is that we are overriding `$material-dark` variable that exist in `node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_dark.scss`. Here you can use any static value or pre-defined framework colors that exist in `node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_colors.scss`, with the help of `map-get` function as the colors are defined as key-value pair. So what you can do with this approach is, just find the background values (or anything else) you want to override inside `_dark.scss`, for dark theme.

**Note** that this approach is to override framework defaults. If you want to define any color and then use inside a component, this approach might not be what you are looking for, this works best to override defaults.

**Second approach** is to define your colors inside `vuetify.theme.themes.dark` that exist in `nuxt.config.js`

```js
vuetify: {
    treeShake: true,
    customVariables: ['~/assets/scss/vuetify.scss'],
    theme: {
      dark: true,
      themes: {
        options: { customProperties: true },
        dark: {
          header: '#3739FF',
          footer: '#101721'
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

Vuetify provides `primary, secondary, accent, info, warning, error, success` by default. If you change any of these values, they will be overwritten with yours. If you add any other value like `header, footer, etc.` they will be added with lighten/darken variants.

These values can be used in a couple of different ways:

1. with `color/background/background-color` props like `<v-btn color="header" />`
2. apply background with class `<div class="primary" />` or custom `<div class="footer" />`
3. apply font color with class `<div class="primary--text" />` or custom `<div class="header--text" />`
4. using lighten variant with `<div class="header lighten-2" />`

[more info about colors](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/#classes)

So the values you add here are not for overriding for component defaults, only to create extra colors or override `primary, success, error etc.` colors.